# What are the changes in TCP communication between PC to android device and android to android?

Tags: android, tcp

I can send and receive data between Android devices. But when I try to communicate with PC, I can send data to PC but can't receive in Android device. Code for send and receive given below:

```
public TcpClient(OnMessageReceived listener) {
    mMessageListener = listener;
}

/**
 * Sends the message entered by client to the server
 *
 * @param message text entered by client
 */
public void sendMessage(String message) {
    if (mBufferOut != null && !mBufferOut.checkError()) {
        mBufferOut.println(message);
        mBufferOut.flush();
    }
}

/**
 * Close the connection and release the members
 */
public void stopClient() {

    // send mesage that we are closing the connection
    sendMessage(Constants.CLOSED_CONNECTION);

    mRun = false;

    if (mBufferOut != null) {
        mBufferOut.flush();
        mBufferOut.close();
    }

    mMessageListener = null;
    mBufferIn = null;
    mBufferOut = null;
    mServerMessage = null;
}

public void run() {

    mRun = true;

    try {
        //here you must put your computer's IP address.
        InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(SERVER_IP);

        Log.e("TCP Client", "C: Connecting...");

        //create a socket to make the connection with the server
        Socket socket = new Socket(serverAddr, SERVER_PORT);
        InputStreamReader ins;

        try {

            //sends the message to the server
            mBufferOut = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())), true);

            //receives the message which the server sends back
            ins=new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());
            mBufferIn = new BufferedReader(ins);

            // send login name
            sendMessage(Constants.LOGIN_NAME);

            //in this while the client listens for the messages sent by the server
            while (mRun) {

                mServerMessage = mBufferIn.readLine();

                if (mServerMessage != null && mMessageListener != null) {
                    //call the method messageReceived from MyActivity class
                    mMessageListener.messageReceived(mServerMessage);
                }

            }

            Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + mServerMessage + "'");

        } catch (Exception e) {

            Log.e("TCP", "S: Error", e);

        } finally {
            //the socket must be closed. It is not possible to reconnect to this socket
            // after it is closed, which means a new socket instance has to be created.
            socket.close();
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        Log.e("TCP", "C: Error", e);

    }

}

//Declare the interface. The method messageReceived(String message) will must be implemented in the MyActivity
//class at on asynckTask doInBackground
public interface OnMessageReceived {
    public void messageReceived(String message);


   }
}
```

Comment: Any questions ?

Comment: `Log.e("RESPONSE FROM SERVER", "S: Received Message: '" + mServerMessage + "'");`. That is outside the while loop. So indeed you will never see that log.

Comment: but i can get the message using messageReceived() in main activity class. And i also get the replay when i connect with android device. My problem is i dont get replay when connect with pc.(am using TCP Client Server app as server in PC)

Comment: You should tell what readLine() returns. The rest is irrelevant. And place that log on the right place. Directly after readLine().

Comment: I dont understand what you trying to say. I said log is not my prob. That message will show in UI. This is one of my class only. Normally readline() returns a string in this.

Comment: This is working code when connecting with android server. Is there anything to specify extra in readline() when connecting with windows server(PC) (eg:size type etc)

Comment: `Normally readline() returns a string in this. `. Yes a line. And now? I asked what it returned. What does it read? Put the log directly behind it. Then you know.

Comment: ok i put the log as you said. But cant see that log.

Comment: Conclusion? Please tell yourself! Why should i put the conclusion here? Does readLine() return something? Or what is it that happens?

Comment: `.(am using TCP Client Server app as server in PC) `. The same app/code as  when used with Android as server?

Comment: ok now i got the log... receive null value.

Comment: client side code is same.

Comment: If readLine() returns null that means that the server closed the socket. But you did not post server code.

Comment: i dont have server code.. I want to communicate with pic microcontroller actually. So downloaded a server app in windows for testing (and this is tested)

Comment: yes you right null value retured when socket closed.  When connection alive nothing returnes.

Comment: You said it was the same code as you used on android?????? Ehhhhh.. You didnt. You came with an irrelevant remark `client side code is same.` Which i understood as yes.

Comment: i said client side code is same... and its working with android server(server download from playstore)

Comment: i had posted here is main part of my Client side android app. I don't have server(bcouse it should be in pic microcontroller) , so i download a third part y app in pc and one in android device. client side code that i have used is same that was i said...

Comment: Im pretty pissed that you did not tell from the beginning that you use different server code on your pc. A lot of time wasted. Also that you did not tell that on android you used a server which you did not program yourself.

Comment: am sorry if i made any misunderstand. And i found the problem and solved.